# Problema relacionado a CORS

Tags: php, javascript, html, cors

Nesses últimos dias tive um problema com o formulário de contatos do meu site, o erro em questão é o CORS. Bom, até aí tudo bem, é um problema que com certeza muito de vocês já devem ter passado. O problema em questão é que, até tempos atrás, estava funcionando perfeitamente, e eu sem fazer nenhuma alteração tanto no lado cliente (JAVASCRIPT) como no lado servidor. De repente, ele foi e começou a dar esse seguinte erro:

> Failed to load LADO SERVIDOR: Redirect from 'LADO SERVIDOR' to 'LADO SERVIDOR' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'LADO CLIENTE' is therefore not allowed access.`

E o pior é que eu já configurei o header no PHP de diversas formas e nada, olha como está atualmente:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","*");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
```

Alguém aí tem ideia do que pode ser e como posso resolver essa situação?

Obs: também já tentei mexer no `.htacess` e também não resolveu nada.

Comment: Que tipo de requisição tem nesse formulário?

Comment: Então Dvdsamm, ele faz uma requisição GET. Se quiser ver o meu site é esse (http://www.adaideias.ga/contato)

Comment: Tentei preencher lá mas não passa do CEP!

Comment: Já tentou header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*') ?

Comment: Já entendi. Consegui preencher todo o formulário. O erro aparece na hora de enviar.

Comment: Não sei se tem a ver, mas o erro que apresenta é: `Redirect from 'http://adaideias.ga/contato.php to 'http://www.adaideias.ga/contato.php`. Será que a falta do "www" na primeira URL está fazendo com que o servidor entenda que é outro domínio?

Comment: Na verdade Dvdsamm sua mensagem chegou aqui, só na respondi na hora pois estava trabalhando. Mas enfim, será que tem alguma coisa a a ver com os novos navegadores? No caso que navegador que você usa? Aqui deu o erro, no computador Windows 10 x64 com o Google Chrome 61.0.3163.100, e num outro computador Windows 7 x86 com o Firefox, não lembro bem qual versão era, pois já devolvi esse pc para o cliente, mas era a versão mais nova do navegador da Mozilla.

Comment: **Será que a falta do "www" na primeira URL está fazendo com que o servidor entenda que é outro domínio?** Então não sei ao certo, mas acho que não, porque olha só, até então estava funcionando perfeitamente, e do nada deu esse erro, e como já disse anteriormente, eu não mudei nada no código Javascript e nada no código PHP, ou seja tem alguma cosia estranha ai, se eu tivesse mexido em um dos dois, tudo bem, mas eu não mexi, e estava funcionando perfeitamente, então ou o problema é no servidor, que acho raro, ou está nos navegadores mais novos, pois isso não está fazendo sentindo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O ÐvÐ estava certo estava faltando o "WWW". O motivo não sei dizer ao certo pois estava funcionando bem antes sem o WWW, pode ser algo relacionado ao servidor mesmo.
Mas é isso problema resolvido.